Why some anti-debugging/malware does `wmiadap.exe /f /t /r`?
It seems some possibly legit software, but also malware does wmiadap.exe /f /t /r. Apparently it's part of their anti-debugging attempts. (On Linux some such software I've seen drops a coredump_filter instead, in /proc.)
I've looked at the Win docs for wmiadap but I don't quite understand the point:

The WmiPerfClass provider updates WMI Performance Counter Classes only when a new performance object is added. You still can run Wmiadap with the /r switch to parse the Windows Driver Model drivers to create performance objects. The /f switch still forces an update of the WMI classes from the performance libraries.

The /t flag is not documented (there, by MS).
How does that wmiadap.exe /f /t /r help with anti-debugging?

I suspect it's because ProcMon (rather than a typical debugger) uses a filter driver. https://medium.com/@demonia/how-i-managed-to-bypass-process-monitor-detection-for-anti-debuggers-and-riot-games-95d06261c1ad I'm not sure how effective the method is though. Remains to be tested.
